# DELETE ... IN hangs after deleting half of a large table (even for deleting 10 rows)

Tags: mysql, mariadb, delete, archive, temporary-tables

I'm having trouble with a DELETE hanging, even for a small number of rows (10) in a large MariaDB InnoDB table.

**Background**

I had a large table (~400,000,000 rows) that needed to have rows archived and removed.  After removing about half of the rows, my archive process started to hang on the DELETE statement.  I took the time to run the (painfully slow) 11-hour OPTIMIZE (ALTER for InnoDB) query to reclaim disk space and hopefully unblock the DELETE process.  This worked until I deleted about half of the remaining rows (down to about 106m out of 200m rows).  I figure I could keep running OPTIMIZE on my giant table to let me remove another 1/2 of the rows, but there must be a better way...

Note that the table does get a lot of INSERT/UPDATE traffic, 1000s of changes per minute.

**Archive Process**

To simplify the archive script, I put the whole process into a stored procedure.  The steps in that procedure are:

1. Flatten and copy up to N rows from the live DB to the archive DB, where the rows are older than 1 month
2. Make a list of archived IDs that are probably in the live DB.
   Store these in a temporary table A
3. Filter temp table A to only include row IDs that are actually in the live DB.
   Store these in a temporary table B
4. DELETE FROM live_db.test_table WHERE test_id IN (SELECT * FROM temp_table_B) ORDER BY test_id ASC LIMIT N;

Now that the table is half empty, step 4 is hanging, even for N = 10
Before the table was half-empty, it worked fine and N = 1000 took ~ 1 sec

**Diagnostics**

Adding an EXPLAIN in the stored procedure lets me know MySQL is planning on using the PRIMARY index for the DELETE, as I hoped it would:

```
id select_type         table          type   possible_keys  key      key_len  ref   rows     Extra
1  PRIMARY             test_runs      index  NULL           PRIMARY  4        NULL  10       Using where
8  DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  tests_to_drop  ALL    NULL           NULL     NULL     NULL  1        Using where
```

Output selected from SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS (some things redacted):

```
---TRANSACTION 6457899980, ACTIVE 14 sec starting index read, thread declared inside InnoDB 3008
mysql tables in use 2, locked 2
242717 lock struct(s), heap size 25507368, 5532268 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 1834147, OS thread handle 0x7f0f68c4a700, query id 204328569 1.2.3.4 user123 Sending data
DELETE FROM live_db.test_table
WHERE test_id IN (SELECT * FROM temp_table_B)
ORDER BY test_id ASC
LIMIT 10
Trx #rec lock waits 0 #table lock waits 0
Trx total rec lock wait time 0 SEC
Trx total table lock wait time 0 SEC
```

(From Comment)

```
CREATE  TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table_B (
        test_id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: How many rows are you attempting to delete at a time?  Is this chunked up or a full delete and, if chunked, how many rows are you doing in a chunk?

Comment: I'm hoping to delete at least 1000 at once, but, as mentioned in the question, even deleting 10 rows hangs.

Comment: By 'hang' I mean it takes a very long time to complete.

In my most recent check, it took 25 minutes to delete 10 rows.

Comment: Try using `JOIN` instead of `IN`: `DELETE t.* FROM live_db.test_table AS t JOIN temp_table_B AS b ON t.test_id = b.test_id ;`

Comment: Does the temporary table use InnoDB as well?

Comment: Yes, the temporary table also used InnoDB.  I didn't specify that in particular, but the SHOW CREATE says so:

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `temp_table_B` (\n  `test_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'\n) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Comment: It might help if the temp table had a primary key/index.

Comment: Using JOIN, suggested by ypercube, was also helpful in speeding up deletions substantially.  It looks like the 'subquery' needed for IN (SELECT * FROM temp_table) is pretty expensive, while JOIN becomes a 'SIMPLE' query.

Comment: Yes, `IN (SELECT ...)` is an anti-pattern in MySQL. At least in older versions, it often leads to poor execution plans.

Comment: Also: I don't see how using table_b instead of table_a is of any help. You could just join to table_a - and save yourself one step.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the `DELETE` statement you used.  I want to see Engine and indexes.

Comment: Tips on big deletes:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig

Comment: Try `ANALYZE TABLE` instead of `OPTIMIZE`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out what's going on here:

Because of how I was choosing test_id values in steps 1 and 2, temp_table B would sometimes be empty. (see question description for step/table context)

Then, with an empty temp_table_B, I was running step 4:

```
DELETE FROM live_db.test_table WHERE test_id
    IN (SELECT * FROM temp_table_B) ORDER BY test_id ASC LIMIT N;
```

which gave

```
DELETE FROM live_db.test_table WHERE test_id
    IN ( <empty> ) ORDER BY test_id ASC LIMIT N;
```

which would hang for quite a while.

Based on this answer: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/86103/144766 , it seems like that empty table was probably compared against each of my 106 million rows, making the do-nothing DELETE take 25 minutes.

Now that I have modified my process to detect the empty table and abort before calling DELETE, I can manually watch for the (data-specific) condition that's causing my list-of-rows-to-delete to occasionally become empty.

***EDIT:*** Even after fixing the empty-in-list problem, my query was greatly sped up by switching from the " IN (SELECT * temp_table) " version to a JOIN version, similar to what is suggested in comments by ***ypercube*** above.  This modification eliminates the 'SUBQUERY' from the execution plan and the query becomes a 'SIMPLE' query:

```
'IN' version:
id select_type         table           type  key     key_len rows Extra
1  PRIMARY             test_runs       index PRIMARY 4       10   Using where
8  DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  temp_table_B    ALL   NULL    NULL    10   Using where

'JOIN' version:
id  select_type  table        type   key     key_len ref                  rows Extra
1   SIMPLE       temp_table_B ALL    NULL    NULL    NULL                 10   Using where
1   SIMPLE       test_runs    eq_ref PRIMARY 4       temp_table_B.test_id 1
```

Comment: Doing a DELETEs like this is really clumsy under the hood (See my old post https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1371/problem-with-mysql-subquery/1384#1384)

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA I assume you mean the 'IN' version?